# How to declare two mutually-containing (circular-dependent) class in C++ with separation?

Tags: c++, class

I really run in to lack of word for saying mutually-contain, but consider:

```
struct A;
struct C;
struct A {
    struct B{

    };
    C* c;
};
struct C{
    A::B* b;
};
```

Quite muddled but makes some sense and compiles.

But when A and C are larger and more complex classes, it's natural to separate them to two pairs of files. Then I'm writing:

```
//a.h
#pragma once
#include "c.h"
struct A{
    struct B{
    };
    C* c;
};
//c.h
#pragma once
#include "a.h"
struct C{
    A::B* b;
};
```

with their corresponding .cpp files. This definitely won't work. So I wonder if there is any way to separate `struct A` and `C` (or better yet if no requirement on final usage)?

Comment: Just forward declare C in a.h? Forward declare of A::B isn't possible so move B out of A

Comment: Forward declaration before or after `#include`? No way to preserve B in A?

Comment: No I don't think thats do able

Comment: `B` --> a_details.h, in `A`: `typedef a_details::B B;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//a.h
#pragma once
struct C;
struct A{
    struct B{
    };
    void call_c_member();
    C* c; // here is you can use incompelete type
};
//a.cpp
#include "c.h"
...
void A::call_c_member() {
   // here is the C class is already complete type
   c->func();
}

//c.h
#pragma once
#include "a.h"
struct C{
    void func() {}
    A::B* b;
};
//c.cpp
#include "c.h"
...
```

Comment: Then I can't call its member function:O

Comment: You can if you move definition of member functions  to a.cpp.

Comment: Oh great! i.e. if I just combine a.cpp and c.cpp, then all is set.